# Autocomplete Text Input only shows items that matches to the first letter only

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, autocompletetextview

I am using Autocomplete Text Input control of xamain. [Autocomplete reference](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/controls/auto-complete/)

Here is my code

```
var autoCompleteOptions = GetAllContacts();
ArrayAdapter autoCompleteAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleDropDownItem1Line, autoCompleteOptions);
speedSearch = FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(Resource.Id.AutoCompleteInput);
speedSearch.Adapter = autoCompleteAdapter;
```

Problem is when i try to search in my contacts, i only get the suggested values that matches the first letter only. for example if [paul@email.com, tom@email.com,bill@xamarin.com] is the list of contacts, if i make search with "xamarin" Autocomplete does not returns anything, but if i search with "bill" it will return.
How can i change an autocompelte's behavior so that any part of string in an array item is searched, it should be returned.

Comment: Use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` w/ custom `FilterQueryProvider` subclass and apply your custom filtering in the `RunQuery` override

Comment: Hi, does my answer for you? Please leave me a comment whether it works or not. Thanks!

Comment: thanks very much, yes i got the idea. i helped. 
i tried an other way and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need create a custom  adapter and implement [IFilterable](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.IFilterable/).

[Here is the source code of ArrayAdapter( java codes)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java), you can find these codes in `ArrayFilter.performFiltering()`:

```
if (valueText.startsWith(prefixString)) {
    newValues.add(value);
} else {
    final String[] words = valueText.split(" ");
    for (String word : words) {
        if (word.startsWith(prefixString)) {
            newValues.add(value);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note `startsWith`, that is why you can't get "bill@xamarin.com" while you input "xa". You need change it to `Contains`.

---

Here is a fast way to achieve your goal.

[Here is a class--`AutoAdapter` (C# codes)](https://gist.github.com/conceptdev/2433227) which has already implemented `ArrayAdapter` and `IFilterable`.

You just need copy and paste it, and then replace:

```
            var matches = from i in a.AllItems
                        where i.IndexOf(searchFor) >= 0
                        select i;
```

with:

```
            var matches = from i in a.AllItems
                          where i.Contains(searchFor)
                          select i;
```

And at last, use `AutoAdapter` in your `MainActivity`:

```
    AutoCompleteTextView textView = FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(Resource.Id.autocomplete_country);
    var adapter = new AutoAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.list_item, COUNTRIES);
    textView.Threshold=1;
    textView.Adapter = adapter;
```

### Note:

You also need to look at [performFiltering](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html#performFiltering(java.lang.CharSequence)) and [publishResults](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html#publishResults(java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.Filter.FilterResults)) methods in `Filter` class

Comment: is there a way that i can bind a custom object with adapter?
like for example you are binding "COUNTRIES" that would be a list of string. i want to bind list of objects and make search in them. can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply a filter to search amongst it and find what you want :

```
  _adapter.Filter.InvokeFilter("your_Search"); 
  speedSearch.Adapter = _adapter;
```

Put this in your text change event